# Does CAS Surrogate Authentication allow retrieving the identity of the primary user?

Tags: cas

When using CAS Surrogate Authentication as per:

https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Surrogate-Authentication.html

is it possible to retrieve the identifier of the primary (admin) user in the application which they're being logged into?

This is for the purpose of logging both the identifier of the impersonated user and the admin user who is performing the action on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the final validation response both attributes are returned that represent the impersonated user as well as the "admin/real" user. Both are also sent to the audit log.